# Missing required parameters for [Route: havence.automail.delete] [URI: havence/automail/{automail}]

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I want to delete the form. When i apply this method its causing the error. I attached my blade file, controller and web.

Blade file

```
  <form action="{{ route('havence.automail.delete') }}" method="POST">
         @csrf
         @method('DELETE')
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

Controller

```
 public function destroy(AutoEmailTemplate $mailTemplates)
    {

        $mailTemplates->delete();

       return redirect('automail/index')->with('success','Mail template deleted');
    }
```

web.php

```
 Route::resource('havence/automail', 'Havence\AutoMailController', [
        'names' => [
            'index' => 'havence.automail.index',
            'create' => 'havence.automail.create',
            'show' => 'havence.automail.show',
            'store' => 'havence.automail.store',
            'edit' => 'havence.automail.edit',
            'update' => 'havence.automail.update',
            'destroy' => 'havence.automail.delete',
            'mail'=> 'havence.automail.mail',


        ]
    ]);

    //EmailReminder
    Route::get('api/email/create', ['as' => 'email.create', 'uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@create']);
    Route::get('automail/mail', 'Havence\AutoMailController@mail');
    Route::get('automail/index',['as'=>'email.index','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@index']);
    Route::get('automail/delete',['as'=>'email.delete','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@destroy']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Route::resource** will generate below route to destory function by default

```
DELETE  /havence/automail/{automail}  destroy     havence.automail.delete
```

You need to pass the URL params to the delete route since the destroy route and controller is expecting a Model binding **$mailTemplates** variable.

*//$automail being the model or primary key*

```
<form action="{{ route('havence.automail.delete', $automail) }}" method="POST">
         @csrf
         @method('DELETE')
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: but why it didnt delete the form?

Comment: what do you mean by delete the form ? are you want to hide this form button ?

Comment: when i click the delete button the data should be delete. But in this case the data didn't delete.